# Trying to compile a python script using Github actions

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions

I have the following script in github actions:

```
    jobs:
    build:
      runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
      container:
        image: artifactory_url/path/python:3.7.9
      steps:
        - name: checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Build Compiled files
          run: |
            mkdir downloads
            cd downloads
            pwd
            python3 -m py_compile ../Library/abc.py 
            ls
            COPY ../qwe.txt qwe.txt
```

I am facing two problems here:

- The compile command doesn't show an abc.pyc file in the downloads directory when the ls command is run.
- The copy command returns an error :
  `/__w/_temp/0cbb9fcc-2932-4339-909e-242f77d6f3b1.sh: 7: /__w/_temp/0cbb9fcc-2932-4339-909e-242f77d6f3b1.sh: COPY: not found` with error code 127 (which I believe is the file not found error).

But the qwe.txt file is just a file sitting in the repo in which the downloads folder has been created.

The repo directory looks like this:

```
Library
downloads
qwe.txt
```

Output:

```
  mkdir downloads
  cd downloads
  
  python3 -m py_compile ../Library/abc.py 
  pwd
  ls
  COPY ../qwe.txt qwe.txt
  shell: sh -e {0}

/__w/repo_name/repo_name/downloads
/__w/_temp/0cbb9fcc-2932-4339-909e-242f77d6f3b1.sh: 7: /__w/_temp/0cbb9fcc-2932-4339-909e-242f77d6f3b1.sh: COPY: not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @alexpdev yeah, you're right. It doesn't fail. Everything works fine until here. I am just surpsied I don't see a compiled python file.

Comment: @alexpdev how would I do that? `python3 -m py_compile ../Library/abc.py -vv`

Comment: @alexpdev I see a bunch of objects and pyc files being created and destroyed/ cleaned up but the connector.pyc file is not created. No errors.

Comment: It's a mystery then... Sorry I couldn't help you can remove the earlier parts of our conversation...  I don't think they will be of much help to anyone

Comment: @alexpdev alright, left some to give some context. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Try looking into the `Library` directory. That directory will have a folder `__pycache__` which will contain the pyc file generated from the `py_compile` command.